# in for loop add +1 key in object

Tags: javascript, json, loops, for-loop

I'm having issues while creating an object and parsing data into it. This is the code that I'm using.

```
var json = { };

for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) { 
      json.number = urls[i];
  }
```

the result i get is

```
{
    "number": "value"
}
```

This is what I would like to get (as many numbers, as there are urls).

```
{
    "number": "value",
    "number2": "value2",
    "number3": "value3"
}
```

Comment: you need to update the key you are setting during each iteration of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't provided `urls` contents.

```
for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) { 
          json['number' + i]= urls[i];
      }
```

Comment: this will result in `{'number0': 'value', 'number1': 'value2', 'number2': 'value3'}`

Comment: @hackerrdave we still don't know what variable `number` if he wants to use it as variable but in this method it will have `number0` as first key

Answer (score 0):

You should update the key you are using in the JSON object:

```
var json = { };

for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) { 
    json["number" + i] = urls[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the key you are setting during each iteration of the loop:

```
var json = {};

for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  if (i > 0) { 
    json['number' + (i + 1)] = urls[i];
  } else {
    json['number'] = urls[i];
  }
}
```

Note that since you are starting with `i = 0`, you will need to add 1 before concatenating it to the string `'number'`.